# Why can't I put two while statements on top of each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am fairly new to python, so this is probably a beginner mistake, but depending on how I order the while statements, it either doesn't load, or doesn't update time.

```
import time
clock = 0
```

Basically, when I put the while statements in this order, the code actually runs, but the second while statement never activates.

```
while 1<2:
    x = inpu(input('What do you want to do?'));
    if x == "time":
        print(clock)
    else:
        print(x)

while 2<4:
    time.sleep(5)
    clock += 1
```

When I put the while statements like this, the code just doesn't run.

```
while 2<4:
    time.sleep(5)
    clock += 1

while 1<2:
    x = inpu(input('What do you want to do?'));
    if x == "time":
        print(clock)
    else:
        print(x)
```

I didn't go into detail about `inpu()`, but it basically says, if you type ___ in the input, it will respond with ___. One of those options is "clock", which will print the clock value.

When I removed everything from the small while statement when it was ontop(replaced everything with a `pass`), the code still wouldn't run. So it isn't a problem with the contents of the second while statement, but most likely the fact that there are two.

Comment: Both loops are infinite. Try finite loops instead.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the order of the `while` statements, your code will never execute the second while loop as it'll perpetually be stuck on the first while loop because `2<4` and `1<2` will always be `True`.

It seems that you're trying to have parallel execution on the clock being updated while the user is interacting with your program. This behaviour can be implemented using other programming techniques such as concurrency or parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

python by default only runs one thread at a time so it can only really focus on one thing at once and a while loop can be thought one big command that never ends. if i remember correctly you can multithread with python and i think that will make it possible to run multiple commands at once. i remember when i was just learning python and had the same question as you!

Comment: here is an example of python multithreading:

```import threading
import time

def task1():
    print("Task 1 started")
    time.sleep(2)  # Simulate work
    print("Task 1 finished")

def task2():
    print("Task 2 started")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Task 2 finished")

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=task1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=task2)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print("All tasks completed")
```